# How to send the <input type="hidden"> in angular so that it binds to component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have letter.ts file as

```
export class Letter {

    clkletter:number;
    inOut:string;
    inOutNo:string;
    inOutDate:string;
    letterIssuedSubBy:string;
    letterFile:string;
    representativeName:string;
}
```

But in html i have used its only two properties: **letter.inOutNo and letter.inOutDate** in the form.Other properties are needed to be hardcoded as they are null or default value.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="letterDate">Letter Date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="letterDate" required [(ngModel)]="letter.inOutNo" name="letterDate">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="chalaniNo">Chalani Number</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chalaniNo" required [(ngModel)]="letter.inOutDate" name="chalaniNo">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So i tried in html to pass the  like in normal html we used to do but it is not working. I tried like this to send the data to component so it gets bind:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="letter.inOut" value="AnnexOne" type="hidden" />
```

I need to send the values from html to component so it gets binded.How can i achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you directly set up this in component only `this.letter.inOut ='AnnexOne'`

Comment: thank you it worked